# How to replace empty values of a column with the groupedby average in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am cleaning a data set and would like to replace all empty sales price with that particular zip code's mean average.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['ABC', np.nan],['EFG', 10000], ['ABC', 15000], 
                        ['EFG', 20000], ['ABC', 17000]],
                  columns=['ZIP CODE', 'SALESPRICE'])

#   ZIP CODE  SALESPRICE
# 0      ABC         NaN
# 1      EFG     10000.0
# 2      ABC     15000.0
# 3      EFG     20000.0
# 4      ABC     17000.0
```

I believe that first I would need to group all the zipcodes together with their mean average sales price

e.g. 
[image: Imgur]

and then replace any empty SALESPRICE value corresponding to a particular zip code with its mean

e.g.

[image: Imgur]

if somebody could please help me out on this as I cannot seem to find any solution

Answer (score 3):

Use [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df['SALESPRICE'] = (df['SALESPRICE'].fillna(
                    df.groupby('ZIP CODE')['SALESPRICE']
                    .transform('mean')))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way you can tackle it using apply:

```
df['SALESPRICE'] = df.apply(lambda x: 
                            x['SALESPRICE'] if pd.notna(x['SALESPRICE']) 
                            else df['SALESPRICE'].loc[df['ZIP CODE']==x['ZIP CODE']].mean(),
                            axis=1
                           )
```